# CSS Background Animation breaks when uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I'm having an issue with some CSS code, it seems to work fine on a localhost and it even works when I view it from a public Dropbox page however once this is uploaded to a server via FTP it seems to break completely and the animated backgrounds nowhere to be seen.

Any suggestions? Here's the CSS, I simply add a DIV tag with the ID 'animatedbg' after the body tag opens and before it closes. The page I want the animation on is here: http://pixelcolony.co.uk

```
 #animatedbg{
    background: none;
    background-image: url('../images/moving-bg.png'), url('../images/moving-bg1.png');
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-animation: snow 50s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 50s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 50s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 50s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  100% {background-position: 100px -500px, -200px -600px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  100% {background-position: 100px -500px, -200px -600px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  100% {background-position: 100px -500px, -200px -600px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  100% {background-position: 100px -500px, -200px -600px;}
}
```

Comment: Check your console on the site you linked, you're getting a lot of errors (incl. the loading of your background images).